# discord.js guild (server) information storage

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that alerts if it sees a specific key word. Is it possible to make theses keywords different per server (guild) without setting up a database for it? If so how does it work?

I have researched for a while and cant find any solution that does not use a database.

Comment: You know you can host MySQL server on your own computer for free though?  Then you can use MySQL Workbench to operate the database with a GUI.  I suspect no one has already written an inline text version for this as a database would be superior in all ways.

Comment: I suppose if you had to do it in line you need a way to iterate over all the values,  you could perhaps put all the values into a string then convert the string into an Array and then loop through each slot from slot 0 to the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this without having a database! discord.js comes with an extended version of the default `Map()`.

## Collections

You can use discord.js Collections to store `guildId`s as keys and values as an array of your keywords.

Read more about collections [here](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/collection/main/Collection:Class).

### Usage

```js
const { Collection } = require("discord.js");

const ignoredWords = new Collection(); // or create a client scoped global variable, for eg: "client.ignoredWords"

const guildId = // get guildId somehow
const keywords = ["foo", "bar"];

ignoredWords.set(guildId, keywords);
```

- #### Getting values

```js
// returns the array of ignored words for that guild, if set.
ignoredWords.get("guildId");
```

- #### Deleting values

```js
ignoredWords.delete("guildId");
```

- #### Mapping

```js
ignoredWords.map((words, guildId) => console.log(`${guildId}: ${words.join(', ')}`));
```

Reference: [Collection](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/collection/main/Collection:Class)

Answer (score 0):

Often times I too need to make a quick discord bot or script and using a database is overkill (to me). What I normally do is store my data in JSON files.

Here is an example for how to use JSON files to read and write data:

```js
// write
const fs = require('fs'); // fs module

const data = {keywords: ["hi"]}; // sample data

fs.writeFileSync('keywords.json', JSON.stringify(data));
```

```js
// read
const fs = require('fs'); // fs module

const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync('keywords.json');
const data = JSON.parse(fileBuffer.toString());

console.log(data);
// prints out {keywords: ["hi"]}
```

One advantage to use this is persistent storage for your data although if you have a slightly heavier workload I can recommend using sqlite, discordjs.guide has an [example here](https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/#creating-the-model).